# How to add test unit to a shared library project using autotools

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, autotools

I'm developing a library which should do a lot of calculation. It uses GNU autotools build system. There is a test project that links to this library and runs various test procedures. Each procedure compares results with pre-calculated values from MATLAB.

I found that testing process is boring and time consuming. Every time I need to do `make`, `sudo make install` in library and `make` in test project, then run the program and see what's going on.

What is the standard way to add `check` target to a library using autotools? It should meet this requirements:

1. User should be able to `make check` and see results without having to install the library itself. The executable should link to recently compiled, and not-yet-installed shared objects.
2. Running `make check` should also run the test program. (Not only compile it). Result of `make check` depends on return value of test unit program. The make should show error if test unit fails.
3. If user decides not to `make check` then no executable should be compiled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're already using autotools, you've got most of the infrastructure already. I don't know the directory layout, but let's say your have: **`SUBDIRS = soroush tests`** in a top-level `Makefile.am`, alternatively, you might have **`SUBDIRS = tests`** in the `soroush` directory. What matters is that a libtool-managed `libsoroush.la` exists before descent into the `tests` directory.

The prefix `check_` indicates that those objects, in this case `PROGRAM`, should not be built until `make check` is run. So in `tests/Makefile.am` => **`check_PROGRAMS = t1 t2 t3`**

For each test program you can specify: **`t1_SOURCES = t1.cc`**, etc. As a shortcut, if you only have one source file per test, you can use `AM_DEFAULT_SOURCE_EXT = .cc`, which will implicitly generate the sources for you. so far:

```
AM_CPPFLAGS = -I$(srcdir)/.. $(OTHER_CPPFLAGS) # relative path to lib headers.

LDADD = ../soroush/libsoroush.la

check_PROGRAMS = t1 t2 t3
AM_DEFAULT_SOURCE_EXT = .cc

# or: t1_SOURCES = t1.cc, t1_LDADD = ../soroush/libsoroush.la, etc.
```

`make check` will build, but not execute, those programs. For that, you need to add:

```
TESTS = $(check_PROGRAMS)
```

What's really good about this approach is that if `libsoroush` is built as a shared library, libtool will take care of handling library search paths, etc., using the *uninstalled* library.

Often, the resulting `t1` program will just be a shell script that sets up environment variables so that the *real* binary: `.libs/t1` can be executed. I only mention this, because the whole point of using libtool is that you don't need to worry about how it's done.

---

Test feedback is more complicated, depending on what you require. You can go all the way with a parallel test harness, or just simple PASS/FAIL feedback. Unless testing is a major bottleneck, or the project is huge, it's easier just to use [simple](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Simple-Tests) (or scripted) testing.

Comment: I added a hand-written test suite program in `tests` beside `src` subdir. It works fine now. Just read about parallel/serial harness. In my case it's impossible to make thing concurrent. Because I'm testing a chained inference engine, in which each output is input of another inference system. Only thing remaining is to change return codes to 77, 99 and 0.

Comment: @soroush - While I often use parallel `make -j`, my projects aren't big enough to justify the complexity of a 'complete' parallel test harness. A [recent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17172310/make-disable-parallel-building-in-subdirectory-for-single-target-only) question asked about how to *disable* parallel testing for the very reason you mention! A return of (0) from, say, `main` is still a `PASS`, and (1) is a (soft) `FAIL` - maybe you could set `TESTS` to a shell script that runs the tests in order, and handles return values in a way you prefer.